# Why Gulp 4 base option generate file in my current folder

Tags: gulp

There are so many guide for gulp 3,  when following vscode guide(which use version 3), but I am use gulp 4 after run `npm install gulp`

I want to compile scss in `projectroot/jsp/scss/*.scss`, output to `projectroot/jsp/out/css/...........`

```
// Sass configuration
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var { resolve } = require('path')
var cssOutput = resolve(__dirname, './jsp/out/css')
gulp.task('sass', gulp.series(function (done) {
    return gulp.src('jsp/scss/*.scss', { base: './jsp/out/css' })
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(function (f) {
            done()
            console.log(f.base)
            return f.base;
        }))
}));

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('sass', function () {
    gulp.watch('jsp/scss/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
}))
```

when I run `gulp -f gulpfile.js`

it output index.css in my scss folder

How I solve this problem?

here is my folder

[image]

I know there are many guide about version 3 , but I am use version 4...

Answer (score 0):

In your case you do not need the `base` option.  This is sufficient:

```
return gulp.src('jsp/scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("jsp/out/css"))
```

I will try to explain what I think is happening in your original code.  See the explanation of the base option, from [glob base from gulpjs documentation](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/concepts#glob-base):

> Glob base
>
> A glob base - sometimes called glob parent - is the path segment
>   before any special characters in a glob string. As such, the glob base
>   of /src/js/**.js is /src/js/. All paths that match the glob are
>   guaranteed to share the glob base - that path segment can't be
>   variable.
>
> Vinyl instances generated by src() are constructed with the glob base
>   set as their base property. When written to the file system with
>   dest(), the base will be removed from the output path to preserve
>   directory structures.

That last sentence is key.  The base will be removed - so when you return the base in the dest function it has no effect.  You set the base but it gets removed leaving the gulp.src path of `'jsp/scss/'` as the actve directory structure.

That is my best guess as to what is happening when you return the same base that gets removed.

Now in my simplified code, the base is automatically `'jsp\scss'` (everything before the glob *).  Which gets removed so we don't need to worry about the `scss` folder anymore.  So what folder structure do you want: `'jsp/out/css'`

[Also, you chose a base which is not part of the file's directory structure - that seems strange to me (if not illegal).  The purpose of base is to indicate later in src which folder structure to use AFTER the base, not including base.

So for example if you used a base of 'jsp' you would end up with its descendant folder structure 'scss/etc.' following whatever you put into gulp.dest which would act as the parent directories.  ]

Comment: But I have set ` { base: './jsp/out/css' }`, Your anwser is correct, But I want to know why we don't need base options?